# How to compute the generalized inverse of an arbitrary (finite or infinite dim'l) complex matrix using a least squares method?

Tags: pseudoinverse, generalized-inverse

I am trying to compute the generalized inverse of an arbitrary (finite or infinite dim'l) complex matrix using a least squares method.

Any idea for the finite and infinite cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Finite dimensions**

The details of the finite dimensional case are in [How does the SVD solve the least squares problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/772039/how-does-the-svd-solve-the-least-squares-problem/2173715#2173715). The input matrix is
$$
\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}
$$
and the pseudoinverse solution is derived.

Specific cases (underdetermined, overdetermined) are derived in [What forms does the Moore-Penrose inverse take under systems with full rank, full column rank, and full row rank?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537880/what-forms-does-the-moore-penrose-inverse-take-under-systems-with-full-rank-ful/2200203#2200203) and [Pseudo-inverse of a matrix that is neither fat nor tall?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971211/pseudo-inverse-of-a-matrix-that-is-neither-fat-nor-tall/2181445#2181445)

The computational process is detailed in [What is step by step logic of pinv (pseudoinverse)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75789/what-is-step-by-step-logic-of-pinv-pseudoinverse/2197696#2197696)

The SVD in connected to the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra in [When pseudo inverse and general inverse of a invertible square matrix will be equal or not equal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871297/when-pseudo-inverse-and-general-inverse-of-a-invertible-square-matrix-will-be-eq/2236009#2236009)

The geometry of the pseudoinverse solution is touched on in [Least squares and pseudo-inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294796/least-squares-and-pseudo-inverse/2177874#2177874)